# how to create new column on the basis of word matched

Tags: python, pandas

how to add a new column on the basis searched item like if dataframe column contain BX-- then in new column it should replace it with BOX as there are more than 30 short form

i think dictionary would be best option for replacement

```
 mapping= {
'BX': 'BOX', 
'CS': 'CASE', 
'EA': 'EACH', 
'PK': 'PACK', 
'None': None
  }
  import pandas as pd 
   lst = ['BX', 'EA', 'EA', 'PK', 'BG','CS'] 
  df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
      df.map(mapping)
```

somehow i am not able to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows.

```
# first define a mapping
mapping= {
    'BX': 'BOX', 
    'CS': 'CASE', 
    'EA': 'EACH', 
    'PK': 'PACK', 
    'None': None
}

# then apply it with map (assuming your abbreviations are 
# stored in column short and the result should be stroed 
# in long)
df['long']=df['short'].map(mapping)
```

With the following test dataframe

```
lst = ['BX', 'EA', 'EA', 'PK', 'BG','CS'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(short=lst)) 
df['short'].map(mapping)
```

It outputs:

```
Out[447]: 
  short  long
0    BX   BOX
1    EA  EACH
2    EA  EACH
3    PK  PACK
4    BG   NaN
5    CS  CASE
```